# bst style numeration \cite{} with number instead autor

Tags: bibtex

I modified a .bst I got from the web, and even when I managed to add the numbered references with numbers, adding some preamble modifications:

```
%%% preamble modifications

patch \@lbibitem to print the current number before the authors
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}
  {]}
  {]\bbl@box{\theNAT@ctr} }
  {}{}

%%%%
```

whenever I write \cite{} I got the author/year names instead of a numbered citation. How could I change that?

My charged options in the preamble:

%references
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib,etoolbox,lipsum,ifthen}

Plus the modified above. I got some latex errors but it doesn't bother to me as far as I got a good result, and if when uploading the paper to the arxiv, it will not provide me problems. I need the numbered citations for normal usage, but this issue is helping me to understand how much I don't know about LaTeX and bibtex (offtopic for comment only: I did not modify/create .tex to include a .bst style, that I suppose I have to upload to the arxiv as well, right?).

Comment: Do please tell us if your tex file loads a citation management package, such as `cite`, `natbib`, or `apacite`. If so, do you load these packages with any particular options?